# Node.js use single-file dependency in npm module

Tags: node.js

I have a single file (either a .js or .node generated with C++, but works the same) that I can use in node.js by calling:

```
var addon = require("./addon");
```

It's not an official package or anything; it has no package.json (and I want to keep it that way).

This above code works fine if I run it in a simple node.js application, but how do I include it in a node.js library? For example:

```
exports.addon = require("./addon")
```

This doesn't seem to work, I tried changing the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "addon": "file:./addon.node",
}
```

but when I use

```
require("addon");
```

later it says it can't be found. [**EDIT**: after I run `npm publish` and then `npm -i mymodule` in another file]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing your own library and want to include you add-on there, I would build a file structure like this:

```
index.js
addon/cpp-generated.js
addon/other.js
...
```

Then from index.js you can just do:

```
const cpp_generated = require('./addon/cpp-generated')
```

I've only used `.js` extensions. You need to change a configuration file to allow for new extensions (like the `.node` that you mention.)

There is no need to mention the file in your `package.json` for things to work. It may be needed there if you run a build, although it should get included because of the `require()` statement anyway.

So it looks like you're doing it right except maybe for the extension (your example shows `.node`.)

And to make sure it gets published, I would add it to the list of files:

```
"files": [
    "index.js",
    "addon/cpp-generated.js",
    ...
]
```

Comment: Hi thanks, it's still not working for me, this is exactly what I'm doing: In my module file, I have a statement: exports.addon = require("./addon"), and in my module folder (which is totally separate from any other node.js folder), the addon.node file is in the same directory as the main mymodule.js file (which itself has its own package.json etc...), the problem: when I run npm publish in my mymodule folder, and it gets published to npm, then when I download it in my other folder (with the main node project), with npm -i mymodule, addon.node doesn't download

Comment: Basically, it works when its on my own system, but how do I get it to "take with it" the addon.node file when I run npm publish?

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks for editing your question. I'm not too sure. I would say you may need to add it to the list of `files`. I've edited my answer.